How do I solve the integral $\int \frac{e^x}{\left(1+e^x\right) \left(2+e^x\right)}\mathrm{d}x$?
Is this solution wrong?
I have tried solving using partial fraction. But the answer don't match.
I have got the answer using substitution, but want to know what am I doing wrong here.
My solution:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)(2+e^x)}&=\frac{A}{1+e^x}+\frac{B}{2+e^x}\\
\implies e^x&=A(2+e^x)+B(1+e^x)\\
\implies e^x&=e^x(A+B)+2A+B\\
\implies\,A+B=1&,\,2A+B=0\\
\implies A=-1&,\,B=2\\
\implies\int\frac{e^x}{(1+e^x)(2+e^x)}\,dx&=\int\frac{-(2+e^x)+2(1+e^x)}{(1+e^x)(2+e^x)}\,dx\\
&=-\int\frac{1}{1+e^x}\,dx+2\int\frac{1}{2+e^x}\,dx\\
&=2\ln(2+e^x)-\ln(1+e^x)\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{(2+e^x)^2}{1+e^x}\right|+C
\end{align*}$$
Correct answer is $\ln \left|\frac{1+e^x}{2+e^x}\right| + C$.

An error in your calculation is $$\int\frac{1}{1+e^x}\,dx=\ln(1+e^x)$$And similar for another integral.
If you take derivative on $\ln(1+e^x)$, you get $\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}\neq\frac{1}{1+e^x}$.
Following your method, let $y=e^x\implies dy=e^xdx$, so$$\int\frac{1}{1+e^x}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{e^x+e^{2x}}(e^x\,dx)=\int\frac{1}{y+y^2}\,dy=\int\frac{1}{y(1+y)}\,dy$$ Then you can use partial fraction to solve it.

thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for..

Let $w = e^{x}$. Then we can apply the partial fraction decomposition method:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{e^{x}}{(e^{x} + 1)(e^{x} + 2)}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{x})}{(e^{x} + 1)(e^{x} + 2)}\\\\
& = \int\frac{1}{(w + 1)(w + 2)}\mathrm{d}w\\\\
& = \int\frac{(w + 2) - (w + 1)}{(w + 1)(w + 2)}\mathrm{d}w\\\\
& = \int\left[\frac{1}{w + 1} - \frac{1}{w + 2}\right]\mathrm{d}w\\\\
& = \ln|w + 1| - \ln|w + 2| + C\\\\
& = \ln(e^{x} + 1) - \ln(e^{x} + 2) + C\\\\
& = \ln\left(\frac{e^{x} + 1}{e^{x} + 2}\right) + C
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{e^x}{\left(1+e^x\right)\left(2+e^x\right)} d x &= \int \frac{2+e^x}{1+e^x} \cdot \frac{e^x}{\left(2+e^x\right)^{2}} d x \\
&=  \int \frac{2+e^x}{1+e^x} d\left(1-\frac{1}{2+e^x}\right) \\
& =\int \frac{2+e^x}{1+e^x} d\left(\frac{1+e^x}{2+e^x}\right) \\
& =\ln \left(\frac{1+e^x}{2+e^x}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

As pointed out in a previous answer, you've made a mistake when computing the antiderivative of $1/(1+e^x)$, one method to compute it is the following:
$$\int \frac1{1+e^x}\mathrm dx=\int \frac1{1+e^x}\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}\mathrm dx=\int \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\mathrm dx=-\log(1+e^{-x})+k $$

$$I(a,b)=\int\frac{1}{(x+a)(x+b)}\,dx$$
$$I(a,b)=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\int\frac{1}{x+a}-\frac{1}{x+b}\,dx\right)$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx=\ln|x|+C \implies \int \frac{1}{x+a}\,dx=\ln|x+a|+C$$


$$\ln|a|-\ln|b|= \ln \left(\frac{|a|}{|b|}\right)$$

Using the above results;
$$I(a,b)=\int\frac{1}{(x+a)(x+b)}\,dx=\frac{1}{b-a}\ln \left(\frac{|x+a|}{|x+b|}\right)$$
Now using the above result;
We substitute $e^x=t\implies e^x\,dx=dt$
$$\int \frac{e^x}{\left(1+e^x\right) \left(2+e^x\right)}\mathrm{d}x\implies \int \frac{1}{\left(t+1\right) \left(t+2\right)}\mathrm{d}t=I(1,2)$$
And there you go!
$$I(a,b)=\ln \left(\frac{|t+1|}{|t+2|}\right) = \ln \left(\frac{|e^x+1|}{|e^x+2|}\right)+C\implies \ln \left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+2}\right)+C$$

In general, let $f$ be a rational function. Then the integration $$\int f(e^x)~dx$$
can be solved by using the substitution $u=e^x$. This is because $du=e^xdx\implies dx=\dfrac{1}{u}~du$. Therefore, the transformation makes the integral becomes $$\int f(u)\dfrac{1}{u}~du$$
But $f(u)\dfrac{1}{u}$ is again rational, which have standard techniques in integrating, so we are done.
For example, in this case, the required integral becomes $$\int\dfrac{1}{(1+u)(2+u)}du$$
By partial fraction, we are done.

Even though the numerator may not contain $e^x$, we can still use this method.
Example. $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{e^{3x}+e^{x}-2}$.
With the substitution $u=e^{x}$, we have the required integral becomes $$\int\dfrac{du}{u(u^3+u-2)}=\int\dfrac{du}{u(u-1)(u^2+u+2)}$$
which can be done by partial fraction.
